# Reputation graph after linking SF and SU

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, stack-exchange, user-accounts

After linking i was granted 100 reputation, but it isn't shown on [graph](https://serverfault.com/users/6244?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top)

Comment: Perhaps someone could turn this into a feature request as opposed to a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graph only tracks the reputation you gain/lose for the questions and answers you post. Auxiliary bonuses (and rep gained / lost on deleted posts) don't show.

**Update:** These are now present on the graph.

Answer (score 2):

It is shown on the graph - you can see it by going to the very first date on the graph - you will notice that the graph now starts at 101 whereas before account association it was at 1.

Answer (score 0):

You received a 100 point bonus for linking your accounts.

Comment: I think he realizes *why* he got the reputation, but he's right in that the bonus rep doesn't show up on rep graphs.

Comment: Your rep graph is only going to be showing rep gained and lost via questions and answers. It does not take into account bonuses that you receive for things like associating accounts.