# Association +100's not showing in rep graph?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, linked-accounts, association

Yesterday, I associated my accounts and earned the +100 rep. But on the rep graph on my profile page, the +100's aren't displayed.

Is this a bug or an intended behavior?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7971/reputation-graph-after-linking-sf-and-su

Comment: @DMA57361: Thanks for sharing the link. But's quite confusing anyways...

Answer (score 3):

Association bonuses now show up on the reputation graph.